# PHP Sec: .inc File Practices For Mitigating SQL Based Attack Vectors

Tags: php, mysql, security

Just a quick "top down" question concerning PHP include files. If I have include files with SQL DB connection information, is there any added risk to having all of these files included on every page in a header include file? Or should I include the files on a case by case basis?

To my understanding it's not until you utilize SQL methods like query() that the risk of SQL based attacks becomes present (granted this is poor wording on my part; the idea of security is to assume every attack could happen at any time). But what I'm not sure of is if by including the files all at the same time on every page you instantiate the connection/socket and leave the door open to nefarious things.

Also, if I put these includes behind a password protected directory in my file structure, will my scripts still be able to access them? Is it possible to have .htaccess allow these files out but not let users into the directory?

I don't necessarily have access to a shell or terminal to do any root level file structuring or permissions, so any edits or implementations need to be done above root level.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL injection is a vulnerability where user data gets interpreted as code. Your inclusion example does not feature any user input, so has nothing to do with SQL injections. In PHP, you can very easily spot injections because they all look like:

```
$query = "SELECT a, b FROM t WHERE x = '$val1' AND y = '$val2'";
```

As opposed to

```
$query = "SELECT a, b FROM t WHERE x = :val1 AND y = :val2";
```

---

As for the second part of your question, yes you can do that. The `.htaccess` file only controls what users can request through the web server. File inclusions are done at the filesystem level, completely bypassing it. In fact, you should have as little code directly accessible to the clients. Many frameworks encourage this sort of folder structure:

```
/var/www/code/ <-- most PHP code here
/var/www/html/ <-- where your index.php is
```

If the webserver is set up to only serve files from the second folder, there's no way for anyone to read the files in the `code` folder.

Answer (score 1):

- The connection code isn't relevant to SQL injections.
- When, where and how often the connection code is run is not relevant either.
- Include scripts are not masked by `.htaccess` settings. PHP and Apache are different layers. PHP can access and include() any file.
- File extensions like `.inc` for include scripts do easily expose connection information, if that extension isn't actually bound to the PHP handler.
- Above "root level" commonly just means one directory up from the DOCUMENT_ROOT. Even the most simplistic hosters *do* usually allow to create a neighboring dir to `htdocs/` or whatever.